# How can I plot this on latex?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

Hi all,
I have been trying to draw this 3D scheme of a river with trapezoidal shape with its floodplains, could you please give me some gidence on how to plot this in overleaf?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably smarter ways, but here's a try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) coordinate(A1)--++(4,0)coordinate(A2)--++(1,-1)coordinate(A3)--++(2,0)coordinate(A4)--++(1,1)coordinate(A5)--++(4,0)coordinate(A6) ;
\draw(-1,3)coordinate(B1)--++(4,0)coordinate(B2)--++(1,-1)coordinate(B3)--++(2,0)coordinate(B4)--++(1,1)coordinate(B5)--++(4,0)coordinate(B6) ;
\foreach \x in{1,...,6} \draw[dotted](A\x)--(B\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]